# Place Multiple fields in one MYSQL row

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am fairly new to MYSQL so this may be an easy question but I have not been able to find anything on it.

I am wondering how you would go about inserting into one row a series of strings separated by comas?

For example, some one inputs in 2 different fields a movie and the year the movie came out.  I want this to then go into one row like "Movie, year", and then later retrieve that info from the database and breaking it into 2 separate fields again.

Thanks.

Comment: its going to be a lot easier, having one input for 'movie' and another for 'year'

Comment: What if I have say input for top 10 movies, should I just make it all in different rows as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple example, assuming you have a  table that's called `movies` with the columns `movie` and `year`.

`INSERT INTO movies (movie, year) VALUES ('Movie 1', 1995)`.

You can also insert multiple movies at once, by just adding multiple groups behind the `VALUES`:
`INSERT INTO movies (movie, year) VALUES ('Movie 1', 1995), ('Movie 2', 2011), ('Movie 3', 2014)`

Selecting the movies at a later moment could be done by running the following query:
`SELECT movie, year FROM movies`